# How to Add/Remove Views?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

From what I understand from the knockoutjs docs and other materials, it is common practice that once `Views` (including those that are nested) are bound to a `ViewModel` 'adding/removing' `Views` is done by toggling css properties like display and visibility.

But what is common/best practice when the intent is to *actually* add/remove a DOM element that is a knockoutjs template or component?

How should the HTML be inserted into the target view? And how should re-binding be executed, if it is not automatic?

Comment: IMHO i like to use `Templates` which are flexible . i really haven't got chance to work on `components` which does serve for same purpose *re-usable*

Comment: Like @supercool, I use Templates as well, and jQuery/jQuery UI can be leveraged to do pretty much anything you want, and you can simply add a flag on your ViewModel to toggle these transitions. So I would have a `<div`> with an `id`, and I bind my `Template` (which has all of the bindings for that ViewModel) to that `<div>`.

Comment: Check out the component binding. You can create "Layers" in your app that can dynamically show any component you pass to it. Typically you would pass the component's name and a params object.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the "if" binding, unlike "visible" it will actually add/remove the elements from the DOM.

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html

Answer (score 0):

Example of a "View Layer" responsible for presenting components.

**Template**

```
<!-- ko if: componentName -->
    <div data-bind="component: { name: componentName, params: componentParams }"></div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

**View Model**

```
function LayerViewModel() {
    if (!(this instanceof LayerViewModel)) {
        return new LayerViewModel();
    }
    var self = this;
    this.componentName = ko.observable(null);
    this.componentParams = ko.observable(null);

    this.showView = function (componentName, componentParams) {
        self.componentName(componentName); 
        self.componentParams(componentParams || {});
    };
    this.dismissView = function () {
        self.componentName(null); 
        self.componentParams(null);
    };
}
```

How you communicate with this layer is up to you. I usually use signals.